# How to stack multiple graphics/marks/backgrounds on a single TextSymbolizer in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sld

I tried simply adding two marks to a graphic, but only 1 got rendered. I tried adding two graphics to a TextSymbolizer, but only 1 got rendered.

I tried adding two TextSymbolizers to the same rule, and it partially worked; they both got rendered, but they got rendered in different positions or stacked in the wrong order.

To fix the wrong order, I tried changing their `priority`, but this caused them to never render on the same position. That's probably because of the `space-around` VendorOption, so I set that to -1000.

This made it work in about 75% of the cases. I got them both to render, and in the correct order, but sometimes, I get one of the layers rendering in a different spot, or two different TextSymbolizers will overlap because of the negative `space-around`. The Text has varying length, so I can't use fixed sizes etc.

My desired result can be seen in the image below; A mark (of type square) with a stroke stacked ontop of a bigger mark (also square). I tried creating a new mark (by implementing MarkFactory etc), but I only want the stroke on the inner mark, and I couldn't find any way to make an edge "unstrokeable".

Any way to accomplish this in an easier way? Perhaps a way to get multiple strokes on a mark?

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 2):

In general in SLD to draw two items for a feature you need two rules. This is complicated in TextSymbolizers as the label placement system tries hard to avoid overlapping labels (which is what most people want most of the time) as you have found out. The easiest fix for your problem is to manually turn label conflict resolution off using the following [vendor parameter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#conflictresolution).

```
<VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
```

However you might want to investigate [graphic resizing](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/labeling.html#graphic-resize)

```
<VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</VendorOption>
```

which would allow you to have a single graphic with text over it. You might find this [tutorial](https://wiki.state.ma.us/confluence/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+SLD+-+Graphics+with+Labels+Inside) useful too.

Comment: I'm currently using stretch to make the label fit. I have tried using a picture, but because of blending/AA or something like that, it makes the border or the inner shape very ugly. Is there any way to "save" etc. the size of the label, so the marks can use that and instead of being stretched?